# How to Validate Negative BigDecimals in scala play Framework FORMS?

Tags: scala, validation, playframework-2.0

I want to validate (do not allow) Negative amount values , in my POST Request
Following is my Validation trait which have Form mapping,

bigDecimal has precision and scale, but how to make sure of negative bigDecimals coming in the request?

```
  trait BICValidation extends CommonValdidation {
      implicit val bICForm = Form(
        mapping(
          "id" -> optional(number),
          "name" -> text,
          "description" -> optional(text),
          "bId" -> optional(number),
          "amount" -> bigDecimal
        )(BIC.apply)(BIC.unapply)
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
"amount" -> bigDecimal.verifying("amount must be negative", a => a < 0)
```

and see the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms#Defining-constraints-on-the-form).

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark my answer as correct, if it is... :p

Comment: I started with the docs :) Not sure how/why this applies to BigDecimal but it does and it works -- obviously some casting/conversions/implicit stuff happening behind the scenes. (My use case was the reverse - I needed to ensure any positive value except zero... `bigDecimal.verifying("Multiplier must be greater than zero", a => a > 0)`)

Comment: I'm back :) Was looking for how to handle min/max validation of BigDecimal in a form. For Long values it's simply: `"myfield" -> longNumber(min = someMinValue, max =  someMaxValue)` That format however doesn't compile with BigDecimal. The above answer nonetheless works and can be applied to both the Long and BigDecimal used cases.